# Make UIGestureRecognizer to receive touches started on subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I attached a custom `UIGestureRecognizer` to one `UIView` which fills almost the whole screen. This view contains a small subview which needs to receive normal touches as well.

**Problem:** Touches started on this subview are not handled by the recognizer attached to its parent.

I want the gestureRecognizer to be first priority and work even if the subview is touched. How can I forward all touches started on this subview to its parent as well in order that my gestureRecognizer can do its job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution! It's actually quite simple.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     // Forward this message up the responder chain
     [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent: event];
}
```

The call to super in `touchBegan` of the subview is all it takes.
Found it on this blog
[Allow superview to recieve events caught by subview](http://www.learningiphone.com/2010/10/post-a-day-8-allow-superview-to-recieve-events-caught-by-subview-2/)